# Orderby Ascending on a list error asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, model-view-controller, ef-code-first

Hi everyone I am building an application that allows the users to submit posts and I am trying to use orderby on a list in ascending order but I get this error

Error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable'2[myproject.Models.NewsPostVM,System.Nullable'1[System.Int32]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[myproject.Models.NewsPostVM]'.
>   Controller

```
public ActionResult News()
{
    var posts = db.NewsPosts.Select(d => new NewsPostVM()
    {
        ID = d.ID,
        Heading = d.Heading,
        Body = d.Body,
        Images = d.Images.Select(i => new NewsImageVM()
        {
            Path = i.Path,
            FileName = i.DisplayName
        }).ToList()
    }).ToList();
    var post= posts.OrderBy(m => m.ID);
    return View(post);
}
```

view

```
@model List<MyProject.Models.NewsPostVM>
@foreach (var p in Model)
{
    <div class="w3-container w3-center">
        <h5><b>@p.Heading</b></h5>
        <p>@p.Body</p>
        @foreach (var image in p.Images)
        {
            <img class="img-thumbnail" width="150" height="150" src="~/Images/@image.Path" />
        }
        <h6>@p.Date</h6>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Either change your model definition to accept IEnumerable `@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.NewsPostVM>` or add `ToList()` to return a list from your _controller_ like this: `var post= posts.OrderBy(m => m.ID).ToList();`

Comment: Use `var posts = db.NewsPosts.OrderByx => x.ID).Select(d => new NewsPostVM() { ... }).ToList();` and delete `var post= posts.OrderBy(m => m.ID);` - its more efficient that the answers (but do not use `var` and it would have been obvious)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call `ToList` on your model data before assigning it:

```
var post= posts.OrderBy(m => m.ID).ToList();
return View(post);
```

Alternative you could change Model for your view to accept IEnumerable (if you are just going with foreach through it, IEnumerable is ok):

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.NewsPostVM>
```

Comment: Thank you, you have solved my issue will mark it as answered when I can

Comment: @ARandomUserNamedChuck  you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using 'var' as the variable type, the compiler chooses IOrderedEnumerable to be the best suitable type. However your view expects a list.

use 'ToList' to force the result to be a list:

```
var post= posts.OrderBy(m => m.ID).ToList();
```

You can avoid this unexpected behaviour by specifying your variable types like:

```
IList<NewsPostVM> posts = posts.OrderBy(m => m.ID).ToList();
```

Comment: you couldn't jsu assign IEnumerable to List, your second line won't compile

Comment: You're correct. Changed it to use .ToList() as well. This is a little bit more code, but ensures that variable types don't 'magically' change for newer users.